# Can't understand why my || is not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a really simple game (even without an interface). You are supposed to type what action would you like to do (attack or block). But why my (`enemy_hp > 0 || hp > 0`) statement doesn't work? The loop goes forever.

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        int hp = 10, enemy_hp = 10;
        String attack = "attack";
        String block = "block";
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (enemy_hp > 0 || hp > 0) { 
            System.out.println("It is your turn, attack or try to block");
            int your_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //Chance to block an attack
            int enemy_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
            String action = userInput.next(); 
            if (action.equals(attack)){
                System.out.print("You attacked your enemy and ");
                if (enemy_block_chance1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("he blocked it");
                }
                else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 0){
                    enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 2;
                    System.out.println("managed to hit, now his hp is " +enemy_hp);
                }
            }       
            else if (action.equals(block)){
                System.out.println("You dicided to block");
                your_block_chance1 = 0; 
            }
            System.out.print("It is your enemy turn, he decided to ");
            int enemy_action = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
            if (enemy_action == 1){
                System.out.print("attack you,");
                if (your_block_chance1 == 0){
                    System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                }
                else if (your_block_chance1 != 0){
                    hp = hp - 2;
                    System.out.println(" and you didn't block it, now your hp is " +hp);

                }
            }
            else if (enemy_action != 1){
                System.out.print("do a heavy attack");
                int heavy_attack_chance = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if (heavy_attack_chance == 1){
                    System.out.println(" but failed");
                }
                else if (heavy_attack_chance != 1){
                    if (your_block_chance1 == 0){
                        System.out.println(" but you blocked it");
                    }
                    else if (your_block_chance1 != 0){
                        hp = hp - 4;
                        System.out.println(" and he managed to hit you really hard, now your hp is " +hp);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (hp <= 0){
            System.out.println("You failed");
        }
        else if (enemy_hp <= 0){
            System.out.println("You won!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want that the while stop when one of the player die? Then you should rather put a &&. Because the || will never be false except if the two players hp are below 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop when the hit points of *either* the enemy or the player have dropped to zero or below, then you want your loop condition to use the logical AND operator rather than OR:

```
 while (enemy_hp > 0 && hp > 0) {
```

This *continues* while both are above zero. It therefore *stops* when either (or both) are zero or below.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition uses `||`, or OR. This means that your loop will continue while the enemy HP is positive, OR the player HP is positive (meaning that it will continue after enemy HP reaches 0). Change it to `&&` instead.